# Verify if a value is in an array using postgresql

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have two columns, c_1 and c_2. The c_1, contains integers, and the other one, c_2, is the result of a `listagg` over numbers delimited by `,`, (so the type is varchar)

I need to verify, row by row, if the value in c_1 is in c_2, How I can do this?

[image]

I already tried:

```
select user_id, c_1, c_2,
       case when c_1 = any(c_2) then 1 else 0 end as c_1_is_in_c_2
from table
```

However, I got the following error:

> ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side

Note: I am working with Amazon Redshift, which is *based* on PostgreSQL

Any help would be fully appreciated!

Comment: Can you update your post with your table declaration, and data types?

Comment: Note that Redshift is not really _based_ on Postgres - it just pretends to be compatible with Postgres (to a limited extent)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE array_field @> ARRAY[int_field];
```

Comment: Thank you, @Ramkumar!
So I tried, and found out that c_2 is not an array, in fact, it is a `varchar`. sorry for that! I edited the question.